# Compile time error in C#

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am new to C# and don't know what is the problem in following code. I got this code by my friend. Basically, its a program to encrypt a string according to the program. Please help me to fix it. I will be highly thankful.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class Class1
    {

        // error lies in these 10 lines mainly.

        private int[,] <key> k__BackingField;

        public int[,] key
        {
            get
            {
                return <key>k__BackingField;
            }
            set
            {
                <key>k__BackingField = value;
            }
        }

        public Class1()
        {
        }

        public string CreatetheCipher(string plainText, int rowsize, int colsize)
        {
            char[] chArr = plainText.ToCharArray();
            int[,] iArr = new int[3, 3];
            int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
            int i3 = Enumerable.Count<char>(chArr);
            for (int i4 = 0; i4 < rowsize; i4++)
            {
                for (int i5 = 0; i5 < colsize; i5++)
                {
                    if (i2 < i3)
                    {
                        if (Char.IsUpper(chArr[i2]))
                            i1 = Convert.ToInt32(chArr[i2] - 65);
                        iArr[i4, i5] = i1;
                        i2++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        iArr[i4, i5] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            int i6 = 0;
            char[,] chArr1 = new char[3, 3];
            for (int i7 = 0; i7 < rowsize; i7++)
            {
                for (int i8 = 0; i8 < colsize; i8++)
                {
                    for (int i9 = 0; i9 < 3; i9++)
                    {
                        i6 += key[i7, i9] * iArr[i9, i8];
                    }
                    char ch = (ushort)i6;
                    chArr1[i7, i8] = ch;
                    i6 = 0;
                }
            }
            string s = String.Empty;
            for (int i10 = 0; i10 < 3; i10++)
            {
                for (int i11 = 0; i11 < 3; i11++)
                {
                    s = String.Concat(s, chArr1[i10, i11]);
                }
            }
            return s;
        }

} // class Class1

public public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Class1 a = new Class1("SWEETLORD-OlUXOmMhEiQO");
        System.Console.WriteLine(a.CreateTheCypher());
    }
}
```

Here's the compiler error message

```
prog.cs(9,24): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `<' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
prog.cs(9,28): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
prog.cs(9,45): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `;' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
prog.cs(15,23): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `<'
prog.cs(15,27): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `>'
prog.cs(19,16): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `<'
prog.cs(19,20): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `>'
```

Comment: What the heck `<key>` does supposed to mean? It's definitely not a valid C# syntax.

Comment: Remove <key> which is what causes this.

Comment: Seems like a decompiled source rather than written by someone. A few decompilers produce such invalid source code for compiler-generated code.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, originally it was `public int[,] key { get; set; }` - the C# compiler then generates a property name that is not legal C# (but is legal IL) so that there can be no conflict with user-defined variables (and so users can't muck with the compiler-generated code except through reflection).

Comment: How do we know this is not someone requesting help to reverse engineer the licensing code of a commercial product?

Comment: @hatchet: We don't care if it is.  There is nothing malicious about the question.  Any tool can be used for good or ill.

Comment: @BenVoigt There is a thing called copyright law. The last time I saw a question like this, a search showed that they first posted the question on a hacker site, admitting their purpose (cracking license keys), and after a few hours without an answer, posted a cleaned up version of the question here. However, it's not a very good question on its own. "help me fix it", that alone is enough to judge it by.

Comment: @hatchet: If the OP is violating copyright, the copyright holder can send a DMCA takedown request and Stack Exchange, Inc. will act on it.  We (the users) don't police copyright issues.  Check meta for discussions on Apple pre-release material under embargo/NDA.  And decompiling is not necessarily evil, plenty of good uses including "I accidentally deleted the source but still have the compiled code" or "I want to know which version of my code this was compiled from".  There's very little here to match it to a particular "bad" use, even if you did want to take on the role of police.

Comment: I didn't recommend closing the question because it might be ethically questionable. I just asked how we could know. And no, I don't want to be an ethics police. But I am ok pointing out duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using coded generated by a decompiler (.NET Reflector, IL Spy, etc). The compile errors tell you what is wrong - characters such as'<' and '>' are not allowed in names of variables, members, or classes.

Rename `<key>k__BackingField` to `key_k__BackingField` or something similar will remove at least the errors you list above.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error you will identify the error. It suggest some invalid character in member name. Your member `<key> k__BackingField` is invalid and replace with `k__BackingField`.

```
    private int[,] k__BackingField;

    public int[,] key
    {
        get
        {
            return k__BackingField;
        }
        set
        {
            k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
```

Note : Your friend provided you code from deassembler so it gives you that error. Please update above code and it will work.

Comment: Even better, just use the auto-property syntax `public int[,] key {get;set;}` This code seems pretty much the compiler generated snippet for autoproperties.